# Invisible Redirect to another domain for a specific url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

We have an issue with an invisible redirect which is not working.

> We need to redirect every request that is not /intranet to another domain

We tried the following code. So I read that using the [P] flag does an invisible redirect to another domain, but it's not working.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/intranet [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://google.be [P,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

When we enter the [P] flag the domain is not being redirected at all, it's showing the current website again.. ( but without issues loading the css and js files )

Without the [P] flag it's redirecting to google, but not invisible..

Comment: `mod_proxy` needs to be enabled and URL will not be redirected. Your web server will act like a proxy and how content of the given URL.

Comment: Hm I enabled proxy_module in apache and it's still not working

Comment: Are you sure it's all enabled? What OS are you using?